# The simplification of $\int_a^{\frac{a+b}2} (x-a)^2 \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\frac{a+b}2}^b (x-b)^2 \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Can someone show me the step-by-step details of calculation of this definite integral?

> $$\frac M2 \left[ \int_a^{\frac{a+b}2} (x-a)^2 \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\frac{a+b}2}^b (x-b)^2 \mathrm{d}x  \right] = \frac{M}{24} (b-a)^3$$

Edit:

> Inspired by the Hint in comment, I tried this way:
>
> $$ \int_a^{\frac{a+b}2} (x-a)^2 \mathrm{d}x = \int_a^{\frac{a+b}2} (x-a)^2 \mathrm{d}(x-a)$$
> use $u$ substitute $(x-a)$
> $$ \int_0^{\frac{b-a}2} u^2\mathrm{d}u $$
>
> because $ (x-b)^2 $ is an even function  $ (x-b)^2 = (b-x)^2 $
> so for the second part ( I'm not sure for this transform )
> $$ \int_{\frac{a+b}2}^b (x-b)^2 \mathrm{d}x = \int_{\frac{a+b}2}^b (b-x)^2 \mathrm{d}x $$
> $$ \int_{\frac{a+b}2}^b (b-x)^2 \mathrm{d}x = -\int_{\frac{a+b}2}^b (b-x)^2 \mathrm{d}(b-x) $$
>
> use $w$ substitute $(b-x)$
> $$ -\int_\frac{b-a}2^{0} w^2\mathrm{d}w = \int_0^{\frac{b-a}2} w^2\mathrm{d}w $$
> so the original formula can be transfromed to
> $$ M\int_0^{\frac{b-a}2} x^2 \mathrm{d}x    $$
> it is easy to get
> $$ \frac M3 x^3 \left.\right|_0^{\frac{b-a}2} = \frac{M}{24} (b-a)^3 $$
> P.S. this question is the 1st I post in this site, I don't know the rules first

Comment: Hint use : f(x) = f(l+u-x)

Comment: L , u are upper and lower limits

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please include work you have tried yourself: in that way, it is easier for other people to help you. Moreover, for homework-like questions as this one, the site's policy is to ask for your own work.

Comment: @Hrodelbert Okay, next time I'll.

Comment: @Mann I add some details I tried inspired by your hint, Was I right ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't see the trick as hinted in the comment, do it the "hard" way:

$$\begin{align}&\int_a^{\frac{a+b}2}(x-a)^2dx=\left.\frac{(x-a)^3}3\right|_a^{\frac{a+b}2}=\frac13\left(\frac{(b-a)^3}{2^3}-0\right)=\frac{(b-a)^3}{24}\\{}\\&\int_{\frac{a+b}2}^b(x-b)^2dx=\left.\frac{(x-b)^3}3\right|_{\frac{a+b}2}^b=\frac13\left(0-\frac{(a-b)^3}{2^3}\right)=-\frac{(a-b)^3}{24}\end{align}$$

Now just add and multiply the whole thing by $\;\dfrac M2\;$

Comment: I add some details I tried, Was I right ?

Comment: It's fine, though you really don't need to do the passing $\;dx\;\to\;d(x-a)\;$ as in both cases you get exactly the same...